# How to use CSS selectors

Tags: css

What are the CSS selectors (for e.g., `+`) and how do we use them? Is there a list of all the selectors? Links to relevant sources will do.

Comment: -1: I don't understand the question. Could you provide a better example of one of these 'metas' in use in CSS?

Comment: Don't close it as not a real question. Clearly 4 of them understood what he was asking for and there is even an accepted answer. Edit it if it's not clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [**CSS specifiction** (here CSS 2.1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/), [section 5 *Selectors*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Specifically, the `+` is called *adjacent sibling selector*:

> #### 5.7 Adjacent sibling selectors
>
> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2 share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).
>
> Thus, the following rule states that when a P element immediately follows a MATH element, it should not be indented:
>
> ```
> math + p { text-indent: 0 }
> ```
>
> The next example reduces the vertical space separating an H1 and an H2 that immediately follows it:
>
> ```
> h1 + h2 { margin-top: -5mm }
> ```
>
> The following rule is similar to the one in the previous example, except that it adds a class selector. Thus, special formatting only occurs when H1 has class="opener":
>
> ```
> h1.opener + h2 { margin-top: -5mm }
> ```

You might also be interested in [*CSS 3 selectors*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about selectors? If so, they're used to specify on which elements the following rules should be applied. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 1):

They're called CSS selectors (the particular one you used is an "adjacent sibling selector"), you can read more about them at [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're talking about selectors, in which case you should read the [Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) (and possibly [Forgotten CSS selectors](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201002/forgotten_css_selectors/)) as well as the [CSS2 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) and [CSS3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) on the subject.